# Помогите реализовать патерн Мост (Bridge)

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Составить программу, что обеспечивает создания ежедневнгоо и Недельного отчета продаж для некоторых магазинов в формате текстового файла и строки string.

Что здесь будет абстракцией а что реализацией?И как их отличать ввобще.

Comment: Главная абстракция тут на текущий момент - поставленная задача. Что такое магазин, откуда берутся продажи... Всё слишком абстрактно

Comment: Да это обычная задачка на с++.Для того что бы продемонстрировать работу патерна.Особых наворотов там ненужно.На полчаса.Только понять не могу где абстракция а где реализация

Comment: Хе, ну допустим - Абстракции: `Магазин{продажиЗаПериод(from, to)}`, `ПисательОтчётов{write();}`, `Отчёт(ПисательОтчётов){get(Магазин)}`. Реализации: `МагазинБерёзка: Магазин`, `ЕжедневныйОтчёт:Отчёт`, `ПисательОтчётовВФайл:ПисательОтчётов`

Comment: Я не думаю что там нужно создавать еще магазины.Там просто абстракцией будет например отчеты, а реализацией записи в формат файла и строки.Или наоборот.Этого я и не знаю

Comment: Там в задании скорее делается упор на сам паттерн.А не создание магазинов

Answer (score 1):

Пример: пусть ваша программа управляет файлами в различных файловой системе, для чего Вы от класса `CFile` порождаете потомки `CFATFile` и `CNTFSFile`. А еще файлы могут быть либо текстовыми, либо двоичными - да еще и в каждой файловой системой. Если просто порождать потомки, то получится уже четыре класса. Кроме того, код будет дублировать друг друга, а подклассы окажутся привязанными к реализации - поскольку никто не гарантирует одинакового поведения для `CFATTextFile` и `CNTFSTextFile`.

Выход в разделении файловых систем и вида файла в разные иерархии классов. То есть, пусть от `CFile` порождены `CFATFile` и `CNTFSFile`, но не более. А классы текстовых и двоичных файлов `CTextFile` и `CBinFile` порождены от `CAbstractFile`, который содержит в себе указатель на `CFile`. Теперь операции текстовых и двоичных файлов вызывают виртуальные функции `CFile` - а исполняются те, что нужно. Пример кода таков (не проверял)

```
// Это классы отвечающие за физическую реализацию
    class CFile {
    public:
        virtual void doIt1 () = 0;
        virtual void doIt2 () = 0;
    };
    // В конкретных классах виртуальные функции
    // исполняют несколько полезных вещей непосредственно 
    // с файловой системой.
    class CFATFile : public CFile {
    public:
        void doIt1 () { format("c:");         };
        void doIt2 () { loadVirus("OneHalf"); };
    };
    class CNTFSFile : public CFile {
    public:
        void doIt1 () { mustdie("windows");   }; 
        void doIt2 () { catchHim("Bill");     };
    };
    // А это классы, отвечающие за файлы на более высоком уровне 
    class CAbstractFile : {
    public:
        virtual void processFile () = 0;
    private:
        // Аргегация низкоуровневого файла
        CFile* m_file;
    };
    class CTextFile : public CAbstractFile {
    public:
        // В зависимости от класса m_file исполнятся
        // разные функции
        void processFile () { m_file->doIt1(); };
    };
    class CBinFile : public CAbstractFile {
    public:
        void processFile () { m_file->doIt2(); };
    };
```

[Источник](http://www.realcoding.net/articles/most-bridge.html)